# How to setup correctly the cookie lifetime using react-cookie-consent and gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookie for gatsby websites?

Tags: cookies, lifetime, gatsby-plugin, gdprconsentform, cookieconsent

I'm trying to set up a gatsby site where I want to set (at least) the google analytics cookie. I have installed react-cookie-consent as well as gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies. My questions is:

Why does the lifetime of my cookie configured via the Cookieconsent prop always remain on "session"? when it is set to true. I tried to configure the prop expires = {365} but it doesn't work either.

Thank you!

In my Index.js :

```
      <CookieConsent
// debug
location='bottom'
style={{ background: 'rgb(13 168 220)' }}
buttonStyle={{ background: 'rgb(148 130 110)', fontSize: '13px' }}
buttonText='Accept'
declineButtonText='decline'
expires={365}
onAccept={() => {
  // alert('Accept was triggered by clicking the Accept button');
  Cookies.set('gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics', 'true');
}}
enableDeclineButton
setDeclineCookie
cookieName='gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics'
```

> This website uses cookies to enhance the user experience.See our privacy policyfor more.

In the gatsby-config.js file :

```
plugins: [
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies',
  options: {
    googleAnalytics: {
      trackingId: 'MY-ID', // leave empty if you want to disable the tracker
      cookieName: 'gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics', // here can you change the cookie name
      anonymize: true // default
    },
    googleTagManager: {
      trackingId: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_TRACKING_ID', // leave empty if you want to disable the tracker
      cookieName: 'gatsby-gdpr-google-tagmanager', // // here can you change the cookie name
      dataLayerName: 'dataLayer' // default
    },
    facebookPixel: {
      pixelId: 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_PIXEL_ID', // leave empty if you want to disable the tracker
      cookieName: 'gatsby-gdpr-facebook-pixel' // // here can you change the cookie name
    },
    // defines the environments where the tracking should be available  - default is ["production"]
    environments: ['production', 'development']
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution given by Mastermindzh himself (the author of the plugin) :
When setting the cookie, we can pass the 'expires' props directly like that :

```
Cookies.set('gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics', 'true', { expires: 365 });
```

I tested it , it's working as expected!!!